# ffmpeg download and retry failed segments

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am using `ffmpeg` to download some streams to a `mkv` file:

```
ffmpeg -y -i https://file.com/myfiles.m3u8 -c copy /tmp/test.mkv
```

In some cases, there has been some issues downloading some of the parts, and the mkv files has parts where it freezes for some seconds before continuing. I am now forced to check the file manually (by watching) and then redownload if it has any issues.

I guess this happens because `ffmpeg` temporarily is not able to download some of the segments referred in the `m3u8`?

Is there some way that I can force ffmpeg to retry failed segments? Or at least abort if it happens? I am kind of looking for a way to get rid of the manual checking of the content.

Comment: Typically, m3u8s extracted from videos on most major sites are temporary URLs, and subject to all sorts of bizarre patterns that cause them to expire and delay (I can't explain it in short terms; have a gander at the .m3u8s extracted by yt-dl -g. If I was you, I would try downloading the m3u8 with something like curl and then running the downloaded file through ffmpeg, that way you aren't having to deal with external data.